# Check roles assigned to user

Tags: db2

In a DB2 database, I have created a few roles and granted a user to some roles like:

`GRANT ROLE "Role1" TO USER "User1"`

`GRANT ROLE "Role2" TO USER "User1"`

How do I check in `SYSCAT` or `SYSIBMADM` tables which user (`User1`) has access to which roles (`Role1` , `Role2`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT GRANTEE, ROLENAME, ROLEID FROM SYSIBM.SYSROLEAUTH`

solved for me

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021978.html). AUTHIDTYPE would be R for role.

Or query [SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050619.html) to retrieve only the role information, e.g., who granted which role to which user.

Comment: Also see my old blogs on that which includes queries and more links: https://blog.4loeser.net/2016/11/db2-security-implicit-privileges.html and https://blog.4loeser.net/2012/11/where-to-find-information-about-granted.html